# how to check new line character for all columns of the table

Tags: oracle, plsql

Assume that there is table that named "GROUP_DETAILS" that has columns (NAME, CODE, DESCRIPTION).

So, the table looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to find new line character in all columns of the table. Then as soon as the column is found, I also want to show as a output. I have already created a script as below;

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (select column_name from user_tab_columns where TABLE_NAME = 'GROUP_DETAILS') LOOP
    select r from GROUP_DETAILS where instr(r, chr(10)) > 0;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I am getting an error as below;

> Error report -
>   ORA-06550: line 4, column 48:
>   PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
>   ORA-06550: line 4, column 12:
>   PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
>   ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
>   PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL?

Comment: Use `r.column_name` to get the column name and change this to dynamic query where you concatenate the column names to the query string in both places. It is also missing the `INTO` clause to get the string in a variable.

Comment: @tadman I think they are not different things when developing

Comment: I offered a different approach in an Answer, but if you are simply curious to know what triggered PLS-00382, it is the chr(10) argument you passed to instr. You must enclose it in single quotes, to make it a string.

Comment: The syntax between MySQL and Oracle can be wildly different. Try and focus your question on just one platform at a time to avoid confusion. Whatever you're working with now, either/or.

Comment: @tadman I got it. It will be helpful my further questions or answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to do this in PL/SQL? You could get the offending rows with plain SQL, like this:

```
select name, code, description,
       case when name        like '%' || chr(10) || '%' then 'name, '      end ||
       case when code        like '%' || chr(10) || '%' then 'code, '      end ||
       case when description like '%' || chr(10) || '%' then 'description' end
       as where_found
from group_details
where name        like '%' || chr(10) || '%'
   or code        like '%' || chr(10) || '%'
   or description like '%' || chr(10) || '%';
```

This will return all the rows where at least one of the columns contains a newline, and the calculated where_found column will tell you exactly which columns have those values. (They would also be clearly visible; the calculated column can be used for further processing, if needed.)

Comment: great. came in handy even after 4 years.